# Trouble deploying my asp.net app to an IIS 7 server

Tags: asp.net, class, deployment, iis-7

I'm having trouble deploying my ASP.NET application to a remote IIS 7 server.
the app When tested Visual Studio 2012 the app runs properly without any issue.

I've written the app to have a couple of pages and some classes to support it.
They are all on the same namespaces. However, I deploy it on an IIS 7 server on another machine it seems to not able to recognize the classes that I've wrote to include with the application.

Here's the solution explorer to show the layout of my project:

[SoltionExplorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc2eS.png)

And here's the error that I've got when deploying it to the remote IIS:
[Here's the Error on my remote IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We5Do.png)

Any help is appreaciated. Thanks.

// Addtiionally===========================

I don't think the issue is because of the wrong version of framework running on the iis server or that it's not compiled right on VS. I've checked  on IIS Netmgr the application pool is all runing on v4 of .NET. I've renamed the extension method to : IsNullOrEmptyOrWhieSpacesz (with a z at the back) it's still showing the same error.. but with the z at the back also. Somehow I think I deployed my asp.net wrong.. I just copied the whole folder that has the aspx file onto my IIS folder. It could be why iis is not seeing my extention method classes.

Comment: I would start by looking at what version of .net you are compiling the project vs. what version is on the server.

Comment: It looks like, that you question is duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174152/isnulloremptyorwhitespace-method-missing Ensure that .Net 4.0 or higher is installed and registered at remote IIS.

Comment: I don't think the issue is because of the wrong version of framework running on the iis server or that it's not compiled right on VS. I've checked  on IIS Netmgr the application pool is all runing on v4 of .NET. I've renamed the extension method to : IsNullOrEmptyOrWhieSpacesz (with a z at the back) it's still showing the same error.. but with the z at the back also. Somehow I think I deployed my asp.net wrong.. I just copied the whole folder that has the aspx file onto my IIS folder. It could be why iis is not seeing my extention method classes.

Comment: Thats right.. changing the project version of .NET solved the issue.. thanks.. THarris and Alexandr.. :)